# Flutter: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with BottomNavigationBar

Tags: android, flutter

I'm following to this tutorial:
https://github.com/fablue/building-a-social-network-with-flutter
and I completely copied and pasted the "Resume" section, but it stops with these errors.

```
Error reading dependency file C:\Users\ritar\AndroidStudioProjects\practice_google_plus\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\snapshot_blob.bin.d: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
Error reading dependency file C:\Users\ritar\AndroidStudioProjects\practice_google_plus\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\snapshot_blob.bin.d: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
Error reading dependency file C:\Users\ritar\AndroidStudioProjects\practice_google_plus\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\snapshot_blob.bin.d: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
Crash report written to C:\Users\ritar\AndroidStudioProjects\practice_google_plus\flutter_08.log;
please let us know at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Program Files\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 435

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:flutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Finished with error: Gradle build failed: 1
```

flutter doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.4.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.112], locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 0.4.4 at C:\Program Files\flutter
    • Framework revision f9bb4289e9 (6 weeks ago), 2018-05-11 21:44:54 -0700
    • Engine revision 06afdfe54e
    • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.54.0.flutter-46ab040e58

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\ritar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-27, build-tools 27.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 24.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)

[√] Connected devices (1 available)
    • 601SO • CB512BVV00 • android-arm64 • Android 7.0 (API 24)
```

I'm glad if you can tell me how to make it work.

Comment: Add your implemented code

Answer (score 0):

This package is not maintained anymore and outdated. It was developed for the early flutter and does not use Dart 2. Also the Readme says:

> This project tutorial is OUT OF DATE. It was created with a very early version of flutter and I am not able to maintain it

[Here](https://github.com/fablue/building-a-social-network-with-flutter/issues/9) is an issue that describes your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Can I know exactly which lines or syntaxes are outdated?

Answer (score 0):

Seems this problem is related with /build directory. Run:

```
flutter clean //removes your /build directory
flutter run
```

As documented in [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17990#issuecomment-393635718)